# Sass command line option to force files with CSS extension as input

Tags: sass

I've been using sass for quite some time however I was wondering if there is a way to force it to use files with a `.css` extension as input instead of the usual `.scss`.

The thing is I would like to use sass to perform minification on a rather old project which was written in pure CSS however stuff like this won't work until I change the extension of the file to `.scss`.

```
sass input.css output.css --style compressed
```

So basically what I am asking is if there is anything I could use to bypass the requirement sass is imposing on me to exclusively use files with `.scss` extension as input? Something like a command line option perhaps which I missed in the official documentation?

Comment: Why can't you just change the extension to .scss?

Comment: For several reasons. One is that the project itself has a lot of CSS code so I essentially need CSS code completion in my IDE to work or otherwise I lose a lot of time. Second problem is that deployment of minified code also needs some baby-sitting so I would like to simplify the process as best as I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some additional documentation book-worming and poking with the `sass` command line tool itself it seems I found the solution. All I needed to do is add the `--scss` argument to let sass know that no matter which file or extension I use it should interpret it as a SASS file. Since my CSS files are of course SASS compliant minification was performed without a trace of complaining.

```
sass --scss main.css main.min.css --style compressed
```

One little (in my opinion badly documented) command line argument and I waste the better part of the day to find it.

Comment: I agree the documentation is TERRIBLE in describing the command line options - I had to look up your post here just to find out the correct syntax for the --style option.

Comment: @Mikepote `sass --help` shows the command line options with a very brief help text.